# For points A, B, does there there a billiard such that any trajectory from A will reflect twice and then reach B?

Tags: geometry, billiards

I'm looking for a kind of generalisation of an ellipse; a shape with a more complicated optical property. I'm not sure how to rigorously define this shape, or prove that it exists, or find an equation for it. So any comments or ideas in that direction would be appreciated.

The ellipse with foci A, B has the property that every billiard trajectory from A will reflect once and then reach B. Equivalently, for any point P in the ellipse, we have 
$$|P - A| + |P - B| = l$$
for some constant $l$.

What I'm looking for is a shape S (probably piecewise defined by two different curves), such that every trajectory from A will reflect twice in S and then go to B.

If the shape is defined by two curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ (as I suspect it will be), then I think my problem is equivalent to the following:

For any $P$ in $\gamma_1$, there exists $Q$ in $\gamma_2$ such that
$$|P - A| + |Q - P| + |Q - B| = l$$
Furthermore, for any $Q$ in $\gamma_2$, there exists $P$ in $\gamma_1$ such that
$$|Q - A| + |P - Q| + |B - Q| = l$$
Note that these conditions are not equivalent.

Can anyone see any way to turn this definition into a more traditional description of a shape? Maybe an implicit equation for the curves $\gamma_i$?

Comment: Does it have to work for _all_ the trajectories? For example two parabolas may constitute some start (you can make the "wrong" region arbitrarily small).

Comment: Not an answer, but a thought: Take $A$ and $B$ each to be the focus of a matching parabolic "cap" (where each "cap" is deep enough to contain its focus), and glue the caps together to make an ellipse-like shape. Trajectories through $A$ that first hit $A$'s cap will reflect to become parallel to $\overline{AB}$ until hitting $B$'s cap, at which point they reflect to hit $B$. Of course, a trajectory through $A$ that first hits $B$'s cap fails miserably to meet the goal, but hey ... I achieved a 50% success rate on the first try! :)  (@dtldarek ... "Great minds", eh?)

Comment: @Blue I wonder if gluing infinite parabolas would be a valid solution ;-)

Comment: I had thought about parabolas, but no, they don't count. It has to work for all trajectories (well actually, almost all trajectories: if the curve is piecewise then we can discount trajectories that hit the corners). 

However in the special case where A = B, two parabola caps does count as a solution!

Comment: @PaulWright My intuition tells me that it could be possible only for $A = B$ for a constant and even number of reflections (of course, intuitions are frequently wrong).

Answer (score 1):

If $A=B$ just choose a circle around the point.

Otherwise, assume without loss of generality that the points are located at $A(-1,0)$, $B(1,0)$.  Then, the billiard consists of three arcs, semicircles of radius $1$ centred at $A$ and $B$ and lying above the $x$-axis, and a semi-ellipse with foci at $A$ and $B$ below the $x$-axis.